# what is the expected value of $x^TAx$?

Tags: random-variables

Assume $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$ is a random variable vector (like a noise sequence). You now want to calculate the following term:

$E\{x^{T}Ax\}$,
where $A$ is a constant matrix.
How can this expression rewritten in terms of, for example, $E\{x^Tx\}$?

Comment: Without determining the distribution of $x$, this is impossible.

Comment: Do you know something about $A$? symmetric, PD, etc ...

Comment: Why don't you go back to the definition of $x^TAx$ as $\sum\limits_{ij}A_{ij}x_ix_j$? The rest follows.

Comment: no, A can be arbitrary

Comment: But to make it a bit simpler you may assume $A=B^TB$.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know if this is what you are after ... there is another answer given too, but if you know the mean and the covariance of $X$ then:

using your comment ($A=B^TB$) and assuming $EX=\mu$ and $cov(X)=\Sigma$ we may write 
\begin{align}
EX^TAX&=E(X-\mu)^TA(X-\mu)+\mu^TA\mu\\
&=E[B(X-\mu)]^TB(X-\mu)+\mu^TA\mu\\
&=\mbox{tr} B\Sigma B^T+\mu^TA\mu\\
\end{align}

Comment: note that $x$ is a vector in my question, so what is $X$ here?

Comment: In general I like the convention: capital letters for random variables :-) and lower case variables for their realizations :-)

Comment: but your result is a vector, however Ex'Ax is scalar. Note that B is a matrix.

Comment: I was not sure if "$x$" is a row or a column ... It was not clear from the question statement.

Comment: I think it should be $\text{tr}\, B\Sigma B^T$ in the last line.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks I just edited :-)

Comment: Can you explain how the E becomes a trace?

Answer (score 6):

It involves covariance between the various $x_i$.
$xx^T$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.  Let $C=E\{xx^T\}$.
The answer is the trace of $AC$.
If $E\{x_ix_y\}=E\{x_i\}E\{x_j\}$, so the $x_i$ are independent of each other, then the answer is $E\{x\}^TAE\{x\}$

Comment: Do you assume $x$ to be centered?